# Making a sorting recursion function in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion

This is edited,

Iam writing a program that will sort an array using recursion.  The program will get the values for the array from a text file. My question is how do I make a sorting function which will sort the array into ascending (increasing) numerical order.

I have to do these steps,

- Find the smallest element in the array
- Move this element into the first position of the array
- Sort the rest of the array by making a recursive call to the sorting function

And this is what I have so far,

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a file name";
    cin >> fileName;

    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open("fileName.txt");

    if(inputFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Your file did not open" << endl;
    } return 1; System("pause");

    int usedVariable;
    if(inputFile >> usedVariable)
    {
        usedVariable + 1;
    } usedVariable++;

    else
    {
        inputFile.close();
        cout << "ERROR: There are no integers in the file";
        exit(1);
    }

    int *x;
    x = new int [usedVariable];

    inputFile.clear();
    infile.seekg(0, ios::beg)

    inputFile >> x;

    inputFile.close();
}
```

So, how do I do this?

Thanks Everyone

Comment: That's not a binary search, that's a selection sort.

Comment: If you can do binary search, your array is already sorted.

Comment: ...and why would you do a recursive selection sort? What do you think you're gaining over iteration in this case?

Comment: Nothing smells like homework in the morning.

Comment: I am confused. I always thought that sorting consisted of comparing elements and (maybe) shuffling them.  Is C++ that powefull?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `std::vector` as "array" and `std::sort` as sort algorithm.

Comment: @Gvegas222, doesn't change anything except first sentence of my answer.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to make what you said? Im just having a hard time trying to do that. Thanks

Comment: Google -> "site:cppreference.com vector", "site:cppreference.com sort". Ability to use manuals and Google is a must in programming.